# Approaches to solve a collatz-ish function

Tags: proof-writing, collatz-conjecture

Let's say we've a function similar to the function in Collatz conjecture.
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
1 \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \text{if $n=1$}\\
\tfrac12n \ \ \ \  \ \ \text{if $n \equiv 0 \ \ $ (mod 2)}\\
n-1 \ \ \ \text{if $n \equiv 1 \ $ (mod 2) }\\
\end{cases}
\\ , \forall \ \  n \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$$

Now,
Can we prove that this will go to $1$ , or *maybe* more formally:

$$
f^m(n) = 1, m \to \infty
$$

If yes, what steps would we take?

Comment: What do you mean "converge to $n$"?

Comment: Sorry, meant 'one'

Comment: You must restrict the domain of $n$, because "otherwise" can also include zero and negative numbers. Note also, that your problem-statement "hopes" that the reader assumes $n$ as integer (which might be "obviously" implied because of the term "even" - but this is still sloppy). So to make a formal proof you need to insert that restrictions in your problem-statement.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms , edited the question - is it formal now?

Comment: Yes, I think it is fine now!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks for pointing out the issues. By the way, Do you think you could comment on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268952/correctness-in-proof-by-induction-for-a-collatz-ish-function ?  :)

Comment: @cipher: coming home just now, being tired. Perhaps tomorrow evening...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will always go to $1$.

Assume $n$ is even; then $f(n)=\tfrac12n<n$. Assume $n>1$ is odd; then $f(n)=n-1<n$. Thus, $f(n)<n$ for all $n>1$. This makes sure that we decrease every time we apply $f$, thus, we must reach $1$ or less at some point, and since $f(n)\ge 1$, we know this must be $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the proof. But does this count as a formal proof? I'd love to see how a formal proof for this is written.

Comment: This certainly counts as formal proof.

Comment: I think one should mentioned that f(n)>=1, because your arguments also are valid for a function f(n)=n-2(n!=1) f(n)=1 (n=1).

Comment: Right. I edited the post to clarify that part.

Comment: @vrugtehagel *formally*, I guess you need to point out that subtracting by $1$ is somehow potent enough to get us to $1$ in the sense that there are only countably many whole numbers and $x\to x-1$ is not convergent on some limit point greater than $1$. That $1$ is the least positive integer is also required.  These are trivial for your example, but perhaps material as examples of formality in relation to the real Collatz.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but *formally* completely depends on context. If you were to do an elemental proof, you're required to point to previously proven theorems whenever you use one; however, since this is just math SE, I usually assume this is not the case (unless otherwise mentioned), and so I do not point out every theorem I use, usually using trivial ones without mentioning I do.